# Adding TextInput only during create, not update using Filament

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I try to build a user form in Filament, which will have password field only in create action, not update.

So I try to limit this way:

```
use Filament\Pages\Page;
...

TextInput::make("password")
    ->required(fn (Page $limewire): bool => $limewire instanceof CreateRecord),
```

The error I get is:

```
Target [Filament\Pages\Page] is not instantiable.
```

How can I get over this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a much easier solution:

```
public static function form(Form $form): Form
{
    $isCreate = $form->getOperation() === "create";
```

and than:

```
TextInput::make("password")
    ->visible($isCreate),
```

Answer (score 1):

Ex. to show the password field on the create page only:

```
TextInput::make('password')
    ->password()
    ->required()
    ->visibleOn('create'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement a seperate form in the CreateUser Page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).